# Parsing Struts tag using s:property

Tags: java, jsp, struts

In one of our challenging application, I am generating few struts tag dynamically in Action class
Once I generated the struts tag, I want it to get it parsed through `s:property`

in my JSP:

```
<s:property value='generateElement("ABC")' escape='false' />
```

in my Java Action

```
public String generateElement(String element){
     return "<s:select id='aaaa' list=\"{'1':'1','2':'2'}\" >";
}
```

in the end I want  to generate Selection box.

How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute JSP code after the JSP has been compiled. So there's no use in returning a JSP tag in your method. Instead, `generateElement` should return the objects that you need in your select, and then reference that property in a `<s:select>` tag that is already in your JSP.